# javascript 'mailto' command

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

What is used to bold the text in a 'mailto' javascript?
After some research i found that %0A is used to insert a new line.

This is my javascript:

```
location.href="mailto:" +
   "?subject=" + "Sub:{!Trigger_Event__c.Title__c}" + 
   "&body="+ "Title:{!Trigger_Event__c.Title__c}"+"%0AOrganization:" + "{!Trigger_Event__c.Account__c}";
```

I need to bold the 'Headline' in the script.

Kindly provide your inputs..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not related to JavaScript. `mailto:` is a protocol, not a JavaScript command. I cannot see `Headline` in your code.

Comment: **Do not use mailto links** - They require the user to have a MUA installed and properly configured - those who use webmail clients won't be able to use those links at all.

Comment: Hi felix.I wanted to bold 'Titile' in the scipt. I wasnt aware if its a protocol or javascript. inputs pls

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Opera does support mailto to web mail, although it is only for a few major providers. You can edit a configuration file by hand to add other providers. Of course, this doesn't count as "widespread support"...

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you want to make the "Title" text in the message body bold. Something like this: `..."&body="+ "Title:<BOLD>{!Trigger_Event__c.Title__c}</BOLD>"+"%0A...` Is that what you mean?

This is not possible. The mailto protocol is very limited. The official definition is in [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068). It's all just plain text. There is no way to specify that the body is some kind of Rich Text or HTML, and even if there were, you cannot rely on it that most browsers and mail clients and web mail systems would support it.